# My login script works local but not online

Tags: php

I am trying to put a simple login password script on a web site.  This works fine doing all the redirects on the local server but when I put it online, if I leave either the user or password empty it redirects to the error page as it should. But if I put anything in the user and password inputs it does not redirect to the secindex.php page instead it stays on the loginold.php page with no redirect.  Can anyone look at this and offer some suggestions?

Login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#00CCFF">

<div style='position:fixed;left:0px;top:-20px;text-align:center;'>
  <h2>You MUST Login to Shopflow to access the system</h2></div> 
  <form method='post' action='loginold.php' target='_top'> 

  <?php
  session_start();
  include('dbcon/dbconnect.php');
  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
  $empresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Emp_ID, Alias from employees   where EmpStatus != 'Inactive' AND Alias != 'Unassigned' ORDER BY Alias");
  echo "<div style='position:fixed;left:125px;top:70px;width:130px;background-color: #00CCFF;text-align:center;border: 1px #000000 solid;'>";
  echo "<span style='color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;'>Login Name</span></div>";
  $dropdown = "<select name='empid' style='position:fixed;left:125px;top:90px;width:132px;border: 1px #000000 solid;font-size:16px' >";
  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='' selected='selected' ></option>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empresult)) {
  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['Emp_ID']}'>{$row['Alias']}  </option>";
  }
  $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
  echo $dropdown . "<br>";
  echo "</div>";
  ?>
  <div style='position:fixed;left:125px;top:130px;width:132px;background-color: #00CCFF;text-align:center;border: 1px #000000 solid;'>
  <span style='color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;'>Password</span></div>

  <input type='password' name='pword' style='position:fixed;left:125px;top:150px;width:130px;border: 1px #000000 solid;font-size:16px' >
  </div>

  <input type='submit' style='position:fixed;left:125px;top:190px;width:130px;border: 1px #000000 solid;font-size:16px' value='Login'>
  </form>
</body>
</head>
```

loginold.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (empty($_POST['empid']) || empty($_POST['pword'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
header("location: error.html"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}
include('php/login.php');
elseif ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: secindex.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
header("location: error404.html"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}
?>
```

php/login.php

```
<?php
include('dbcon/dbconnect.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['empid'];
$password=$_POST['pword'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$tresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE PassWord='$password' AND Emp_ID='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($tresult);
?>
```

edited the loginold.php and added coce for php/login.php to the above

Comment: Possibly you need to change: `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
` to `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: you are most likely getting a database error, `var_dump(mysqli_connect_error())` after you assign the `$con` variable

Comment: no errors just no redirect to the secindex.php page.  Just a blank page with loginold.php in the address box of the browser.  Also changing from mysql_real_escape_string to mysqil_real_escape_string makes no difference.  To be clear the script redirects fine if either the user or password is empty but if anything is placed in both the user and password fields no redirect takes place just loads and displays a blank page.

Comment: @Augwa var_dump(mysqli_connect_error()) returns NULL

Comment: UPDATE***  If I echo $username and $password it returns the proper information so it is getting that far additionally if I echo $rows it returns 0 if I enter the wrong password (this is where it should redirect to the error page) and 1 if I enter the correct password (this is where it should redirect to the site)  I can't for the life of me figure out why this works locally but not online.

Comment: add an exit() after your redirects. if anything out output before or after the header redirect even a single space it will not redirect.

Comment: I've also encountered that not using an absolute redirect also causes problems.

Comment: @Augwa adding exit(); does nothing to change the behavior.  I am wondering should I be using include to do the data base lookup before the redirect?

Comment: I am not familar with absolute redrect

Comment: before you do your "redirect" `var_dump(headers_sent());` if it comes back true then your redirect won't work.

Comment: an absolute redirect would be including the full URL, so instead of `secindex.php` do `http://myhost/path/secindex.php`

Comment: @Augwa the dump return bool(true)  so now the question becomes how to fix it???

Comment: somewhere in your code you are outputting something, you could trying doing an exit before you do the header redirect and view the source to see if that will help you.

Comment: I edited the loginold.php as outlined above.  The problem seems to be with the include ("php/login.php") if I delete that line the first redirect will work but none of the others.  But with the include in there no redirects take place at all?????  Can anyone please help a fella out here?

Comment: You should add in your question the php/login.php page

Comment: include('php/login.php');  - is this the correct path for the file on the webserver?

Comment: What is the OS of both? i.e local and remote servers.

Comment: added the php/login.php to the question as requested.  yes that is the correct path to the file.  The local os is windows using the xampp stack the remote system is linux

Comment: although I am unsure of it it seems as though the php/login.php file is sending somekind of header and I don't see how to make it not do so.

Comment: Your problem is `The header is already sent` it is not happen in windows due to the your source file format. Save your file in Unicode and upload it again to the server.

Comment: sorry to seem dense but how do you save in unicode format?

Comment: @phpnoobie Checkout the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75949/discussion-between-phpnoobie-and-ss).

Answer (score 0):

Use some advanced text editor such as [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) and save your source code files in Unicode then upload them again to server.
In some cases, using MS notepad, it adds hidden symbol at the beginning of the file that it regarded as a text sent before your headers and sessions and leads to such errors.

Checkout the following screen shot from Notepad++:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded and installed notepad++ then downloaded  login.php,  loginold.php, and php/login.php and opened in notepad++ then saved as encode in utf-8 without BOM still the same problem no redirects as long as the include statement is there.

Comment: I have saved all the files login.php loginold.php and php/login.php in unicode but no change only way redirect works is to remove the include statement any ideas?